# File.Delete fails on attempting to delete an opened file but deletes on process exit?

Tags: c#, .net

While calling `File.Delete(file_path)` for a file which is opened in another process, the attempt fails with cannot access error, but on exiting the app (from where the attempt was made) the file gets deleted automatically. After `File.Delete` attempt, the path gets inaccessible for any other operation.

I need to either fail on delete and let the path be accessible through the app or delete the file completely, not on app exit.

Well my code is this :

```
 private bool DeleteFilesAsync(string FileToDelete)
 {
    try
    {
            //Set file's attribute to normal if it is ReadOnly file
            File.SetAttributes(FileToDelete, FileAttributes.Normal);

            File.Delete(FileToDelete);
           //Some bussiness logic to update file's status in database

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log the error
         return false;
    }
}
```

Something wrong here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `File.Delete()` does not delay the deletion of the file on failure (and Windows does not follow UNIX's delete-on-last-close pattern). Are you certain the deletion is not delayed by your own code?

Comment: Post your code for deleting the file, surely there is someone here who can help you.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Windows does indeed have a delete-on-last-close feature. All deletes are handled that way! The only reason that this almost never occurs in practice is because most apps do not open the file with FILE_SHARE_DELETE so it is not possible to delete a used file. But at the Kernel level all deletes are delete-on-close.

Comment: So there may be dependency on which application has opened the file, in my case, sometimes files are being opened into a wpf media player inside the app itself.
Is there any way to cancel the delete command if it has been failed.
The reason, I need to access that path to create new files on it and this doesn't allow?

Comment: @usr, agreed, that was an oversimplification on my part. The behavior is still not the same, though, as on Windows a deleted file remains accessible until its last handle is closed, but on *NIX the file "disappears" and is only accessible to previous openers. Therefore I cannot explain the `after File.Delete attempt, the path gets inaccessible for any other operation` part of the problem.

Comment: @usr, it is apparently possible to clear that flag from the kernel side. Raymond Chen mentions a way in [his article about this topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/06/07/150047.aspx), but unfortunately the link seems to be dead from old age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows does have a delete-on-last-close feature. All deletes are handled that way. The only reason that this almost never occurs in practice is because most apps do not open the file with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` so it is not possible to delete a used file. But at the Kernel level all deletes are delete-on-close.

There might be a way to clear the delete flag by calling `NtSetInformationFile` to set the `FileDispositionInfo` class. This assumes that it is possible to clear the delete flag. It might well be.

Anyway, a more sane approach would be to open the file before deleting it to ensure that exclusive access is available:

```
using(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)) { }
```

After this line passes without exception, we know that the file was unused at the point of opening it. Of course, it might be opened by someone else immediately after this line, but maybe this solution is enough for you.

Comment: Yes this seems to solve my problem with a small window opened. Still looking for a solution of the inaccessible path problem as I need to access the path. Is there any way to force delete the parent directory of that "deleted marked" file? that can solve my problem. Or may be recreate the same path again?